# Requesting clarification on specific gravity

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am unclear why the ratio of molecular weights will yield the specific gravity of a substance relative to the standard substance (usually air or water at a specific T and P). I always took specific gravity to be a function of temperature since densities are temperature dependent, so I would find density data at approximate conditions to calculate specific gravity whenever I needed to.

Answer (score 1):

> I always took specific gravity to be a function of temperature since densities are temperature dependent, so I would find density data at approximate conditions to calculate specific gravity whenever I needed to.

You are correct. Densities, and therefore specific gravity values, are temperature dependent.

> I am unclear why the ratio of molecular weights will yield the specific gravity of a substance relative to the standard substance (usually air or water at a specific T and P).

This requires a bit of unraveling. I'll point out that specific gravity is unitless being the ratio of the density of the substance in question to a particular standard.

**For gases:**

For the *specific gravity* of a gas at sea level, air is assumed as the standard. However I remember gas values expressed mostly as densities g/L or kg per cubic meter.

Assuming ideal gas behavior and STP as defined by IUPAC, the molar volume of any gas is 22.7 liters. So the relative densities of ideal gases would be determined exactly by the relative molecular masses.

**For liquids and solids:**

The standard would be water which has a value of about 1 gram per ml. For solids and liquids atmospheric pressure fluctuations can generally be ignored, but temperature must be taken into account.

The relative molecular masses would, in general, have a poor correlation with specific gravity though there would might be good correlations with some series of similar chemical molecules (for instance the monohalo benzenes).

Comment: Under the "For gases" header, do you mean to say "...gas at sea level, air is assumed as the standard"? Why would we have to make an assumption about the volumes of the gases being compared, isn't density an intensive property?

Comment: @J.Ari - Thank you for the correction. You are correct that I didn't include "air" in the sentence. // I assumed ideal gas behavior because then using PV=nRT at STP the volume of 1 mole of every gas would be exactly 22.7 liters. But of course not all gases conform to the ideal gas model exactly. It is really a matter of the precision of the measurement. To two significant figures I can't imagine any difference. To three maybe a few gases would differ. To six significant figures then a lot will vary from ideal behavior at STP.